# What is the thing at the top of WPF Windows in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

[image]

Is it useful, and how can I toggle it on/off? I would just google it, unfortunately "thing at top of screen in WPF" doesn't really turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a new WPF debugger tool found in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. It shows the live visual tree which can be very helpful for debugging WPF applications.

You can find the feature in this changelog: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

Edit: To disable this, click the left-most button in the dropdown, and then click the left-most button on the resulting live visual tree panel.